# Single page MVC3 website - How to map URL to accept Query String parameters on Home Index

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url-rewriting

I'm creating a website with only one page. Instead of mapping controllers on the URL I want to map query string values.

This is what I want:

```
http://{mysite}/Hello/World
```

I want my Home controller to pick this up (in the Index method) and read Hello into valueA and World into valueB fields.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I made a mistake while trying to create a route. This works for what I need:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```